# How use FloatingActionButton from another XML file in Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I want to use **FloatingActionButton** in Fragment class

`home.xml` is for `class Home extends AppCompatActivity`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.azadgh.app.myapplicationtab.Home">


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

and this is TabCost:

```
    public class TabCost extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabcost, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

How can i use `fab` in `TabCost` ?

I have three Tab similar `TabCost` , I want to when i click `fab` in any Tab Show diffrent `Snackbar` . 
How can i fiexd it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use in Fragment:

```
FloatingActionButton fab =(FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab)
```

As you mentioned, you use `ViewPager` to handle fragments. You can add  `OnPageChangeListener()` to your `ViewPager` and override its methods which are: `onPageScrollStateChanged` , `onPageScrolled`, `onPageSelected`. 
So, when you select any page (in your case, fragment), it will be called and inside it you can set different contents for `Snackbar`.

```
@Override
public onPageSelected(int position) {
    String contentForSnackbar = "default string";
    switch(position){
    case 0:  
      contentForSnackbar = "first fragment";
      break;
    case 1:  
      contentForSnackbar = "second fragment";
      break;
    case 2:
      contentForSnackbar = "third fragment";
      break;
    }

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, contentForSnackbar, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I have three Tab similar TabCost , I want to when i click fab in any Tab Show diffrent Snackbar . How can i fiexd it ?

Comment: How do you handle fragments? `ViewPager` or `FragmentTransaction`? Depending on each case, you can change content of Snackbar. If it is `ViewPager` then you should have adapter which has `addOnTabSelectListener()`  method. If you use `FragmentTransaction` then you can change content when changing fragments

Comment: i use `ViewPager` , i don't undrestand your answer . please explain more ،

Comment: Please, consider to upvote and accept it as answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks for your answer , is very good , i can't  upvote  your answer , because my **reputation** is below than 15   :(

Answer (score 0):

use this code to include cost.xml in home.xml :

```
<include layout="@layout/cost" />
```